# Unit Test in unique relationship between resources

Tags: unit-testing

i'm doing the unit tests for my system, but I find myself in great doubt about how to perform the tests and validation logic for the resources that are related and should be unique in that relationship.

For example, I have the following:

There can not be two products with the same name within the same project. Only applies if they are within the same project, there may be many products with the same name while they are in different projects.

I think I should leave the validation to the database, and wait for an exception in the system, so that my test executes the use case and waits for the exception, so I apply that validation in my ProductRepositoryStub, simulating what the database would do .

On the other hand, it occurs to me to perform the validation within my use case, making the query to the database validating before performing the action, with this the test would be simpler.

This effectively corresponds to a unit test, or should it be an integration test? In my system I have many cases similar to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is a pretty good example of the intricacies involved in unit testing, integration testing, and the boundaries between them and the usefulness of each.

While there's no "right" answer, here's what I would do. Hopefully it provides some insight and helps you figure out what would meet your needs best.

Leaving it to the database to detect duplicates is very reasonable - databases are good at this, and it reduces the amount of code you'll have to write. A simple unique constraint on (product-name, project) will suffice. And indeed, trying to enforce this anywhere other than with a database constraint (like doing a read and then validating in your application logic before writing) could lead to race conditions if you're not very careful about transaction boundaries. So given that using the database to enforce this constraint is the best approach, how do we test it?

**Unit tests:** I think a unit test is a great option here if at all possible. Unit tests should always be the first choice based on the [test pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html). However, your unit test need not test the database's ability to enforce the unique constraint (that's outside the scope of the "unit" you're testing). Instead, your unit test should assert that your system behaves correctly if the database throws an exception due to a unique constraint violation. Does that exception need to be translated to a custom exception at any layer of your application? If so, unit test that. Does your application need to return a particular HTTP status code due to the original or translated exception? If so, unit test that.

**Integration tests:** Because you depend on the database to enforce the unique constraint, there's no way to completely test that the interaction between your system and the database will behave as expected without an integration test. There are a few variations you could use here, and you'll have to decide which, if any, fits your use-case best. In some Java applications, it's a relatively common practice to load your schema into an in-memory H2 database and perform a minimal integration test between your database access class and the test database you've just set up. Other's might prefer a more end-to-end integration testing approach, which would involve running your application against a real database, and then running API tests against that.

You mentioned that you have many cases similar to this one - so consider which approach will scale best to test all the scenarios that you want. The downside of end-to-end tests is that they can be slower to start and more difficult to manage because of their extra dependencies, potentially making your feedback cycle longer. On the other hand, they provide the ability to assert on conditions that are a little bit closer to the production environment.

Comment: thank you very much, your answer is very explanatory and you have clarified several doubts